# Codeigniter Multilevel MySql Query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

I am sorry if this question is unclear but i have done my best to make you understand this situation. I am using codeigniter in this case

I have a table named levels such as

**Table name LEVEL**

```
id  name
1   abc
2   xyz
```

and another table named **courses**

```
id   level   name
1    1,2     apple
2    2,3     android
```

What i want to generate in the query is:
 1. I want to execute the query such that it gives me the respective level names with the courses detail i.e

```
{['name' : 'apple',
  'level' : 
        {'name': 'abc', 'name': 'xyz'}
]}
```

I tries a lot by using the joins but it didnot works for me. Will any one please suggest me the right options for this, what should i do to split the levels ids and get its respective name from the level table.

Comment: The first step, assuming I'm reading this correctly, would be to update your database schema such that you don't store level as a comma separated list. Even still, you'll have to do some grunt work to format this as you're looking to, outside of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use FIND_IN_SET:

```
SELECT * FROM courses c JOIN 
levels l ON FIND_IN_SET(c.level, l.id)
```

I didn't test this query, so it may need some fixing.